# Error: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, android-room

How to insert data into database where primary key is **(autoGenerate= true)**?

here's Tables's code

```
@Entity(tableName = "Account")
 public class Account {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(index = true, name="ACCOUNT_ID")
public int id;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo
private String bank;

@NonNull
@ColumnInfo
private String bal;

public Account(int id, String bank, String bal) {
    this.id = id;
    this.bank = bank;
    this.bal = bal;}

public int getId(){return this.id;}
public String getBank(){return this.bank;}
public String getBal(){return this.bal;}
}
```

**TableDao**

```
@Dao
public interface AccountDao {
@Query("SELECT * from Account ORDER BY bank ASC")
LiveData<List<Account>> getAlphabetizedAccounts();


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
void insert(Account account);

@Query("DELETE FROM Account")
void deleteAll();
}
```

in startActivityForResult I am trying to get EditTextView data like

```
    final Button save = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent replyIntent = new Intent();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EtBankName.getText()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EtBalView.getText())) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent);
            } else {
                String bankName = EtBankName.getText().toString();
                String bal = EtBalView.getText().toString();
                replyIntent.putExtra(_BANK_NAME, bankName);
                replyIntent.putExtra(_AC_BAL, bal);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, replyIntent);
            }
            Intent balIntent = new Intent();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(EtBankName.getText()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(EtBalView.getText())) {
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, replyIntent);
            } else {
                String bal = EtBalView.getText().toString();
                replyIntent.putExtra(_AC_BAL, bal);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, balIntent);
            }

            finish();
        }
    });
```

And onActivityresult I am doing this

```
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == NEW_ACCOUNT_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Account account = new Account(data.getStringExtra(NewAccountActivity._BANK_NAME),data.getStringExtra(NewAccountActivity._AC_BAL));
    mAccountViewModel.insert(account);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(
            getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.empty_not_saved,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
 }
}

Error Line:Account account = new Account(data.getStringExtra(NewAccountActivity._BANK_NAME),data.getStringExtra(NewAccountActivity._AC_BAL));
```

I have tried all removing adding but no solution.My constructor has three parameter and I'm providing two. How to overcome this problem of **auto Id** acknowledge any correction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pasting all the code that you can, won't get you anywhere.

Comment: The compilation error really gives you everything you need to know. You defined an Account constructor with 3 arguments, yet on line 87 in MainActivity you're trying to use a constructor with 2 arguments and that constructor doesn't exist, hence the compilation error.

Comment: @Igor llin in my problem id is set to auto-generate then how I will set that.

Answer (score 1):

As per source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent()
Intent getIntent():Return the intent that started the activity.
So, Instead of using (new Intent()) **getIntent()** will work better in case of startActivityForResult.

And for @Primarykey(**autoGenerate = True**) use 0 (zero). As per source https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/PrimaryKey.html#autoGenerate()
If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0(zero) as not-set while inserting the item. 
for eg:

```
Table table =new Table(0, data1, data2,..);
mTable.insert(table);
```

finally I solved my problem myself.